# Python- Re-loop through file to gain updated information

Tags: linux, python-3.x

I am writing a program in Python that grabs the peak memory usage of my child processes from the "/proc/PID/status" file. I can successfully grab the information but it is only the initial memory usage when the process begins and not the peak memory usage. Here is my code:

```
def worker(self):
    cmd = ["/home/orlando/CountMem","400000000","2000"]
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    id_list = []
    id_list.append(p.pid)

    for num in id_list:
       stat_file = open("/proc/{0}/status".format(num))
       for i, line in enumerate(stat_file):
           if i == 3:
              print line
           if  i == 10:
              print line
    return id_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    count = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = count)
    print(pool.map(worker,['ls']*count))
```

And here is the output I get from this code:

```
Pid:    7839
Pid:    7838


VmPeak:       12 kB

VmPeak:       12 kB

Pid:    7841

VmPeak:     2400 kB

Pid:    7840

VmPeak:     2400 kB

Pid:    7843

VmPeak:       12 kB

Pid:    7842

VmPeak:       12 kB

Pid:    7844

VmPeak:       12 kB

Pid:    7845

VmPeak:     2400 kB
```

Hopefully to make this a bit more clear, I would like to read the "/proc/PID/status" file multiple times until the process ends so that I can get the peak memory usage and not the initial memory usage. Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Maybe keep the value in a variable if it's higher than anything you've seen before?  You might need to parse the line (split()) to get the value, and convert it to an integer, to make the compare.  Sorry if I'm missing something.

Comment: Tell me if this helps. The code uses the pid's to get into the status file, from there it reads through the file and prints lines 3 and 10 which hold the information for the PID and VmPeak. My problem is it only does this once at the beginning. I would like to repeat this process of reading through the file for as long as the actual child processes are executing, printing the PID and VmPeak everytime it reads through the file. Does that clear some of the smoke that I may have created for you?

Comment: You are only reading each file (for each pid) once.  You need to re-read them again and again.  Put a while (condition is True):  around everything.  Terminate when all (?) processes have finished.  Keep a dictionary of peak memory values, keyed by the pids.

Comment: I guess after each loop, check to see if each process is still running.  If not, remove it from your id_list().  So the condition would be while (len(id_list) > 0):

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to do. I thought that it would be a while loop but I just couldn't think of the correct condition. Thanks, I'm going to try and implement this now.

Comment: It worked almost perfectly. The only problem is that once the child processes finished it continued running another set of processes. This may be due to the fact that the code I am calling is written in MATLAB. But that issue is outside of the initial question. Thanks alot, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place a while loop around the for loop checking on the pids.  After each loop, check to see if each process is still running. If not, remove it from your id_list(). So the condition would be while (len(id_list) > 0):